# How to import "MyComponent" instead of "MyComponent/MyComponent"?

Tags: reactjs

By default, one can import a component defined in `./MyComponent/index.ts` by `import MyComponent from "MyComponent"`.

To avoid having 12 tabs named "index" in my IDE, I name the component file `MyComponent.ts` too. But now if I import the component, I have  `import MyComponent from "MyComponent/Mycomponent"`.

Since the file name always matches the directory name, I was wondering if I can add a dynamic resolver to my project configuration, e.g. `tsconfig.json`, which maps `"MyComponent"` to `"MyComponent/MyComponent"`.

Comment: I think this is just a tradeoff with the two patterns you've described. The only thing I can suggest is a third pattern - each component get's an index file that just re-exports the MyComponent/MyComponent. So while you're working on MyComponent, the file in the tab is descriptive; but when you import you can still utilize the index. It means an extra file with very little in it, but it's an option

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `index.ts` file inside `./MyComponent` with the following:

```
export * from "./MyComponent";
```

And then you can import `MyComponent` with the following:

```
import MyComponent from "./MyComponent";`
```